# Unix XML file convert into Flat file

Tags: c, xml, perl, parsing, unix

We are having multiple xml files on unix. We need to convert them into flat files. And we did that parsing for one level of xml file using C (C was used as C can communicate with Teradata fastload which is our target box using inmod and it will complete within one parse other wise in other languages we need to do two times parsing one for converting into flat file and one for loading ito teradata). i.e. the below file

```
<book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
   </book>
```

Is converted into

```
bk101~Gambardella, Matthew~XML Developer's Guide~Computer~44.95~
```

This we achieved by parsing the file in C. But after seeing the original format of xml file which is below. (Please do not consider it as the required file. I am just giving an idea)

```
<book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
             <modified>2010-01-02</modified>
             <modified>2010-01-03</modified>
      <price>44.95</price>
   </book>
```

This should be converted to two records it seems.

```
bk101~Gambardella, Matthew~XML Developer's Guide~Computer~2010-01-02~44.95~
bk101~Gambardella, Matthew~XML Developer's Guide~Computer~2010-01-03~44.95~
```

But now we are feeling that our C code is going to be complex for this req. So we are looking at other options which can be easily used on unix. Can any one please give us any working example codes in different languages/options for unix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XSLT. I use Saxon (Java) which can be run on Unix.

This stylesheet handles both of your XML samples:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output  method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/book">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="modified">
        <xsl:for-each select="modified">
          <xsl:call-template name="dump-line">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
          </xsl:call-template>          
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="author"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="genre"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="dump-line">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/book/@id"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/book/author"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/book/title"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/book/genre"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/book/modified[$pos]"/><xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/book/price"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there are no `modified` elements, one record is output. If there are `modified` elements, it outputs as many records as there are `modified` elements.

Sample output w/modified elements:

```
bk101~Gambardella, Matthew~XML Developer's Guide~Computer~2010-01-02~44.95
bk101~Gambardella, Matthew~XML Developer's Guide~Computer~2010-01-03~44.95
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You have provided excellent working example. Thanks a lot. Your example increased my interest to learn XSLT. I used xalan (c version) to run ur example code and is perfectly working. Stackoverflow geeks are great. Thanks to one and all for all your help and suggestions. I will try out most of the available options and let u know of the final product.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I am able to create simple xslt scripts for much more complex xml files i have with multiple loops. Keep rocking. Because of you now I am able to come out of idea of complicating my 600 lines of C code and starting to learn new language. Now I have to try the same script and execution on my unix after pursuing my organization to use xalan.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad it helped. You should really take a look at Saxon though. The HE edition is still free and supports XSLT 2.0. http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ Xalan does not support 2.0

Comment: I am trying to install Xalan C on my solaris machine. I got the Xalan-C_1_10_0-solaris_28_64-cc_62.tar.gz from http://mirror.candidhosting.com/pub/apache//xml/xalan-c/binaries/ link. In the install page http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/install.html its saying to add xerces lib to path but i dont find it in my downloaded zip. can you help?

Comment: I got the xerces's tar file also downloaded and found that lib. But do we need it for using Xalan for this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading the data into a database, and you have fields that share a many to one relationship with other fields, then you need to make sure your database structure is up to scratch. I.e. one table for the book, and one table for the modification date. Otherwise it will look like there are two books when in fact there is one with two modification dates.

However, if you are loading the data into a database, why are you first converting it to a flat file? You said you wanted to avoid having two passes one the parsing. Well it looks like you'll have one pass to parse the XML and output as a flat file, and another to parse the flat file and enter it into the database. Why not simply parse the XMl and put the data directly into the database?

There are reasons why formats like XML were invented and one is to encapsulate complicated data relationships in text based documents. By converting to a "flat file" you will lose that complexity. If you are then going to import the data into an environment that can handle that complexity and store those relationships...why not keep it?

Does your database have an API, or can it only import flat files?

---EDIT---

It's easier to reply as part of an answer than as a series of comments.

First, thanks for the clarification.
Second, no I cannot provide example code. Mostly since what you want sounds very specific.
Thirdly, I think you have two options:

1) You have a load of C code already written to parse the XML. You have to consider the cost of throwing it all away and writing it again in Perl and supporting that, against the cost of improving it to import data directly into your Teradata database and the cost of maintaining it thereafter.

2) For Perl, there are many XML parsers and in my experience they make traversing an XML tree/data structure much much easier than in C. I'm not a fan of Perl, but I have written code to deal with ready parsed XML trees in C and I have never failed to hate it. By contrast, doing it in Perl is simpler and probably even quicker.

There are a huge number of Perl modules out there to parse XML. I suggest you search the internet for some reviews on them to decide which is easiest or most appropriate for you to use.

There is a Perl module called Teradata::SQL that should allow you to import the data into your Teradata databse. There may be other modules that are easier/simpler/better to use. I have no experience in any of them so cannot make a recommendation. Search http://www.cpan.org for any modules that may be useful.

---

Lastly, I STRONGLY recommend ensuring that you take some time to ensure that the design of your Teradata database matches the data going into it. As I stated above, you clearly have a many to one relationship between modification dates and books, so that means you need a table for modification dates and a table for books and correct many to one relationships in your table design. To put one entry per line, resulting in multiple lines for the same book with only modification date varying is very wrong. There may be other many to one relationships such as author. Imagine book B written by authors A1 and A2 with modification dates of M1 and M2. If you use the approach you discussed above of having one line for each combination, you end up having 4 entries for the same book, and it looks like you have 2 books with the same title but written by different authors.

Spend some time to ensure you understand the structure of the data in the XML files. This should be clearly defined by the DTD.

Comment: Sorry, there was a misunderstanding... Teradata inmod facility is a shared object (dll in windows so in unix) which can be called by fastload utility to get a record to be loaded into teradata. So here i am currently doing only one pass on the xml file. Teradata support for xml is less and there is a shredding option which can only be supported after an upgrade which is not in near future. So we are looking at other options even though they need two passes. Can you please provide any example code in perl/some other which can convert this way? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is an option; check out the [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) tool.

Or, you can also the much easier XQuery, though you might need to coerce it into producing text. The following XQuery script does almost what you want (only a few fields listed):

```
for $book in doc("book.xml")/book
for $mod in $book/modified
return concat($book/@id, "~", $book/title, "~", $mod, "
")
```

You can run this through [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) with

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query '!method=text' script.xq
```

Another popular XQuery processor for Unix is [XQilla](http://xqilla.sf.net), though I'm not sure it can produce non-XML output.

(There may be a smart alternative to my awkward way of generating a newline.)

Answer (score 0):

How about formating the line as `bk101~Gambardella, Matthew~XML Developer's Guide~Computer~2010-01-02,2010-01-03~44.95~`. Of course, special consideration must be taken to the fact that the modified field can contain a list of values. That's about as flat as you can make it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, Ultimately it should be loaded into a Database table. So this record should be split into two records for reporting. We are curently thinking of perl xml parser. Any body knows of any example code on perl which can fulfill the above requirement?

Comment: I bet there are tons of examples if you google it. Is it a requirement that you have to use scripts? Would Mono be acceptable as a tool? The .NET framework has a lot of goodies with respect to parsing and handling XML, making it quite the breeze...